# Sequelize, relations and required attributes

Tags: sequelize.js

I created a sample Express / Sequelize / sqlite app and I run into a weird problem when associating models. My schema is as follows:

One role can have many users.

**Role model:**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Role = sequelize.define("Role", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    shortName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });
  Role.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Role.hasMany(models.User, {
      as: "Users",
      foreignKey: "role_id",
      sourceKey: "id"
    });
  };
  return Role;
};
```

**User Model**

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define("User", {
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  });
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.belongsTo(models.Role, {
      as: "Role",
      foreignKey: "role_id",
      targetKey: "id"
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

**Usage**

Now I try to create a Role and a User and associate them

```
let adminRole = await models.Role.create({
        name: "Admin",
        shortName: "A"
      });

let john = await models.User.build({ // Step 1
             firstName: "John",
             lastName: "Doe",
             email: "John@doe.com",
             username: "john",
             password: "this_should_be_encypted"
           });

await john.setRole(adminRole); // Step 2
await john.save();             // Step 3
```

- Step 1: I just *build* the User, knowing that all attributes are non-nullable.
- Step 2: when calling setRole(). Sequelize invokes an bogus INSERT statement  `INSERT INTO`Users`(`role_id`,`updatedAt`,`createdAt`) VALUES (1, ...`. Presumably to create an User entry that has the correct role ID.

This generates an exception, because of the violation of the non-null constraints.

- Step 3: is never reached.

If I change the order of step 2 and step 3 it works - the user entry is created and then the association is made.

But what should I do if role_id is not nullable as well?

Then there is a real chicken-and-egg situation.

What can I do to avoid this? The only thing I can imagine is to set role_id manually but this is against the idea of an ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here do this.

```
await john.setRole(adminRole, {save: false}); // Step 2
await john.save();             // Step 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that totally solved my problem. One question remains, where can one get this information? Maybe I was too lazy but I did not find it in the official docs.

Comment: Yeah the people who maintain the docs are lazy too, lol. You can find mentions for this in the issues section of the sequelize github. Like https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3321